# Line breaks between dynamically added controls in asp.net ajax updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

Sry, I am missing this basic thing. No clue on how to achieve this.

Here is my Default.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server"  />
    <asp:UpdatePanel EnableViewState="true" UpdateMode="Always" ID="mainpanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="MainPlaceHolder" runat="server">

                 <%--<asp:Button runat="server" id="EditButton" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Edit" Visible="true"/>
                <asp:Button runat="server" id="DeleteButton" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Delete" Visible="true"/> --%>      
                                       <%--<br />--%>               </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="UpdateButton2" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Add" />
</asp:Content>
```

Here is my Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

    }
}

protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;

    if (ViewState["ButtonCount"] != null)
    {
        count = (int)ViewState["ButtonCount"];
    }

    count++;
    ViewState["ButtonCount"] = count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        TextBox t = new TextBox();
        t.Text = "hello"+i.ToString();
        MainPlaceHolder.Controls.AddAt(MainPlaceHolder.Controls.Count, t);
    }   
}
```

When I run this app and when I click button, a new text box control is added every time. Thats Fine. But I want to have a breaking space between each text box control! Pls help me with the piece that I am missing.

I tried with a br tag just above the closing tag of asp place holder. It failed. Extending the question, Am I on the correct path if I want to add two buttons beside every dynamically added text box? sry for a big question. couldnt minimise it more.

Comment: How did the br tag "fail"?  Did it not get rendered?  Did it get rendered but not achieve the line break you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that modifying your code to look like this would work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    TextBox t = new TextBox();
    t.Text = "hello"+i.ToString();
    MainPlaceHolder.Controls.AddAt(MainPlaceHolder.Controls.Count, t);
    Literal lit = new Literal() { Mode=LiteralMode.PassThrough, Text="<br/>" };
    MainPlaceHolder.Controls.AddAt(MainPlaceHolder.Controls.Count, lit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your default.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server"  />
<asp:UpdatePanel EnableViewState="true" UpdateMode="Always" ID="mainpanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="MainPlaceHolder" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static">

             <%--<asp:Button runat="server" id="EditButton" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Edit" Visible="true"/>
            <asp:Button runat="server" id="DeleteButton" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Delete" Visible="true"/> --%>      
                                   <%--<br />--%>               </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button runat="server" id="UpdateButton2" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Add" />
```

Then add this to your CSS:

```
#MainPlaceHolder input[type=text]
{
    display:block;
}
```